# I want to print all Google auto suggestions using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to print google auto suggestion list using selenium webdriver. For this I have written is:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://JDK/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("selenium");
```

I have entered text "Selenium", and google is displaying auto suggestions, I want to get count of all suggestions and I want to print all these.
Kindly guide.

Answer (score 0):

This will meet your requirements:

```
List<WebElement> print = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='sbqs_c']"));
System.out.println(print.size());
for ( WebElement we: print) { 
    System.out.println(we.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");

    WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='gLFyf gsfi']"));
    search.sendKeys("java");

    //change class name as per requirement 
    List<WebElement> printlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//li/descendant::div[@class='sbl1']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

    query.sendKeys("Cheese");
    Thread.sleep(1000); // Wait for suggestions to be loaded
    List<WebElement> allSuggestions = driver
            .findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role=\'listbox\']/li/div/div/div[@class=\'sbl1\']/span"));

    System.out.println("Total No. of Suggestions are: " + allSuggestions.size());

    for (WebElement suggestion : allSuggestions) {
        System.out.println(suggestion.getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.gLFyf.gsfi")).sendKeys("automation");
List<WebElement> suggestions=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul>li.sbct"));
System.out.println(suggestions.size());
for(int i=0;i<suggestions.size();i++){
            System.out.println(i+" "+suggestions.get(i).getText());
}
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul>li.sbct:nth-of-type(5)")).click();
```

Comment: please add page load timeouts.otherwise list size becomes zero